# a linear Diophantine equation in two variables

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given that $\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right)=(5,5)$ is a particular solution to the linear Diophantine equation $18 x+6 y=120$.

determine the number of solutions $(x, y)$ where $x>0$ and $y>0$ .

I can count solutions easily in this case but how to use that particular solution thing? Can somebody give hint?

Comment: When will $6y=18x$ ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Whenever $y= 3x$ ; but how that will help to solve the equation .

Comment: There will be a general solution $x=5+t, y=5-3t$.

Comment: Because as you change one variable you need an **equal** but **opposite** reaction in the other to keep things getting the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$18x+6y=120,$$ i.e., $3x+y=20,$ has particular solution $(5,5),$ by [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation), its general solution is $$(5+k,5-3k).$$

Therefore, its positive-integer solutions are $$\underbrace{(6,2),(5,5),(4,8),(3,11),\ldots,(1,17)}.\\6 \text{ solutions}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$3x+y=20$$

If you agree not to use a given solution, we can get the solutions as follows.

Take $x=k$, then $y=20-3k.$
Hence positive solutions are derived with $1 \le  k \le 6.$
$(x,y)=(1, 17),(2, 14),(3, 11),(4, 8),(5, 5),(6, 2).$

$(x,y)=(5+k,5-3k)$ is derived from substituting $k=5+k$ to $(x,y)=(k,20-3k).$